# Question on permutations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$; $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ be two permutations of $1,2,\dots,n$ and $n$ is odd. Prove that $(a_1 - b_1)^2(a_2 - b_2)^2\dots(a_n - b_n)^2$ is an even number.

I do not know how to start it. Anything I do performing multiplication or anything else cannot give me any minus sign. Please help me.

Comment: Our eagerness to help you is inversely proportional to the number of exclamation marks at the end of your question title.

Comment: Just give me any hint

Comment: Hint: Note that what you have is even if any of the $a_n-b_n$ are even, can they all be odd?

Comment: But how i use it?

Comment: $n$ is odd. How many odd and even values will you have in $1,2, \cdots,n$ ? ... do you know the pidgeon hole priciple ?

Comment: Further Hint: What parity is the sum of an odd number of odd elements?

Comment: The sum of the numbers $(a_i-b_i)$ is $0$, and there are an odd number of them...

Comment: If a permutation acts on an odd number of elements that have a green or a red color, is it possible that every red element is mapped to a green element?